# Error in Ethereum Wallet:"Couldn't estimate gas, resorting to default parameters. Transaction is likely cheaper than the estimate"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, gas-estimate

I am using ethereum wallet for deploying contracts in my private blockchain. But whenever I try to send a transaction in my ethereum wallet it shows an error that says, "Couldn't estimate gas, resorting to default parameters. 
Transaction is likely cheaper than the estimate". When I used my ethereum wallet earlier for deploying contracts in another private blockchain, it didn't say this error and contract deployed successfully.

Can anyone help me to find out what that error says?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the version of my Ethereum wallet into v0.9.3, it worked fine. Earlier it was v0.11.0.